# Give an example of a local homeomorphism $f:X\to Y$ and a subset $A\subset X$ such that $f|_A$ is not a local homeomorphism of $A$ onto $f(A)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

**Give an example of a local homeomorphism $f:X\to Y$ and a subset $A\subset X$ such that $f|_A$ is not a local homeomorphism of $A$ onto $f(A)$.**

I am studying algebraic topology and I am faced with this problem that I have no idea how to answer, I would appreciate any help or suggestion, thank you very much.

Comment: A hint:  take the covering map of $\mathbb{R}$ to $S^1$.  What is a "smallest" $A$ taken onto $S^1$?

Comment: @user539887 $A=[0,1)$?

Comment: Not really the "smallest".

Answer (score 3):

$f: \mathbf{R} \to S^1$ given by $f(x) = (\cos(x), \sin(x))$ is a covering map hence a local homeomorphism. If $A = [0, 2\pi]$ then at $0$ and $2\pi$ the map $f|_A$ fails to be a local homeomorphism.

Comment: Any covering map is a local homeomorphism? Why in this case $f|_A$ is not a local homeomorphism?

Comment: A covering map is basically a discrete disjoint union of copies of the base and acts as a the identity on the copies hence is a local homeomorphism. Roughly speaking.

Comment: Why in this case f|A is not a local homeomorphism?

Comment: Imagine my restriction to be a local homeomorphism at zero. Then its image is an open neighborhood of $(1,0)$ in the circle. Do you see a problem ?

Comment: (At some point you'll need to work out at least something yourself, you know.)

Comment: If we take a neighborhood of zero, the image of this neighborhood is not an open one in $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: Points near the image of zero are points coming from the $2\pi$ side of the interval, so ...

Comment: Every neighborhood of $(1,0)$, is the image of points near zero and $2\pi$?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's right.